# Easiest way to run an unbalanced 2-way ANOVA

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, paired-data, tukey-hsd-test

Trying to help a friend out who has no idea about statistics but who has to compare a few samples for a medical paper.

So we have 6 different types of fingers which underwent 3 different treatments. There are 42 fingers in total which were assigned to these treatments randomly, so n for every combination is between 1 and 5. We took 5 measurements on these fingers, before and after treatment. We're trying to compare the treatments against each other and also whether they had any effect at all.

My stats knowledge isn't great either, but to me that sounds like one unbalanced 2-way ANOVA per measured variable (MANOVA would be a bit far...) - at least to compare treatments against each other. I don't know much about this, but I was hoping to get something out of **Anova** from the **car** package, using Type 3 ANOVA? Can we then use **TukeyHSD** for pairwise comparisons between treatments, even if the distribution of finger types within treatments could vary? That doesn't seem quite right...

Lastly - is the before/after test something completely different to this or should it be done as part of the same test?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

My best advice is, if by "medical paper" you mean something that will be published and valuable for others, that you consult someone a little better versed in analyzing experiments.

It's absolutely unclear to me in what way you think you can consider the "before/after" test as something different from the analysis you are considering.  Isn't the whole point of your study to compare the subjects before and after the applied treatments?

One way to simplify the analysis is to change the dependent variable to account for both the before and after measurements. For example by making the dependent variable the difference between before and after, of the ratio of after to before.

In general, I don't advise this approach, essentially because you are discarding information on your measurements.

The better approach is to use a model that takes into account the repeated measures nature of your data.  That is, the before and after nature of the measurements.  This is usually accomplished with a mixed effects model (e.g. using the nlme or lme4 packages).

As to the specific functions in R.  1) Note that to get type-3 sum of squares from car::Anova, that you need to change the contrast coding in R or your model first.  2)  Forget TukeyHSD. You can read the documentation for that function for some of its limitations.  For a better approach, investigate the lsmeans package, which includes a Tukey adjustment of p-values.